# The following classes could not be instantiated with android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, sdk, android-appcompat

Recently i changed my sdk from 25 to 26 in my app in android studio, i'm getting this weird error in all my xml. At the moment the error is not afecting my app in any way i can see, but is anoying to see every time i have to edit or change something in the xml.
The error here:

---

the following classes could not be instantiated - android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:788)
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)
at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:212)
at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:206)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:250)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:213)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:224)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:146)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.al285790.time2cook"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

EDIT: Added some of my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.al285790.time2cook.recipeInfo.RecipeInfoActivity">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recipeNameText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/photoRecipe"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cho" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dificulty"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/ratingBarDificulty"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:isIndicator="true"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:stepSize="1" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button8"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="giveLike"
                        android:text="LIKE!" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Ingredients"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ingredients"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/superList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Steps"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/stepsList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you use AppcompatTextView use TextView Instead

Comment: I'm just using TextView... but i'm getting the error even in layouts without TextView.

Comment: can you post the xml code ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grayBackground">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TAKE LEAVE BY:"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</FrameLayout>

Comment: I think this is just another native bug with API 26 or support library 26.x. I have exactly the same problem. I am getting used to these problems while updating to newer version of Android.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was getting this error too and tried to fix it by cleaning, rebuilding and invalidating the cache many times.
What fixed it for me was changing the parent theme in `res/values/styles.xml` to one with `Base` e.g.

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30011016/4281480).

Comment: It' worked ! I changed all my parents in styles.xml to Base, and then cleaned and rebuild the code. Thank you a lot! To be fair i was getting used to the error, but now is so much better to work.

Comment: This worked for me as well. For those of you who are using NoActionBar, you'll have to remove the .NoActionBar suffix because it is not included in Base.Theme. But fear not... you can still remove the ActionBar by updating the "windowNoTitle", "windowActionBar", "android:windowFullscreen" and "android:windowContentOverlay" items in your style. See the selected answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478925/why-is-apptheme-noactionbar-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try:

1. Cleaning/Rebuilding

   - Open Android Studio and go to Tools -> Clean project and let the    gradle build run.
   - After completion, go to Tools - > Rebuild project.
   - Done.
2. Invalidating caches

   - Open Android Studio and go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart and click on Invalidate/Restart.
   - Done.

Comment: These suggestions work most of the times but not even working for myself. I'm getting the very same error from the past 5 days which can only be removed by changing versions of those `android.support`. see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802406/android-support-v7-widget-appcompattextview-cant-be-instantiated), this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in Android Studio 2.3.3 and has been reported - [Preview render problem when adding maven.google.com as a maven repo](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65825761)

Unfortunately this bug won't be fixed in Android Studio 2.3.3 but has been fixed in Android Studio 3.0

So let us wait till stable versions are available for Android Studio 3.0

### Update on 26th Oct 2017:

Android Studio 3.0 is in stable channel now. Update it and you won't see this error