# The following classes could not be instantiated android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-xml, android-appcompat

Here are my dependencies of build.gradle(app)

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Here is a part of build.gradle(Project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

When I am going to any `xml` file it is showing me an error **The following classes could not be instantiated:

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)**

I have updated Android Studio to the latest still it shows the error.

I am unable to figure out the problem.Thank you

Comment: have you tried to clean the project? some times its the issue due to sudden closing of AS.

Comment: try to invalidate the cache like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29921076/4428159

Comment: i cleaned and rebuild the project and invalidate cache many times

Comment: everything was fine until I was using `26.0.0-alpha1` . The problem arrised when I changed the version to `26.0.1`

Comment: can you show the code where you using this class

Comment: the `xml` code?

Comment: Same error in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802406/adding-maven-repository-causes-an-error-android-support-v7-widget-appcompattex).

Answer (score 26):

**EDIT**
Whenever You'll add maven repository, this problem will occur.
See same error I'm facing on a question asked by  my friend [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802406/adding-maven-repository-causes-an-error-android-support-v7-widget-appcompattex) as I can't ask.
This can be solved by changing AppTheme in res -> values -> Styles.xml
change your theme from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

It solved mine and don't forget the [actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889207/8244632).

Comment: Yes. I changed to 26.0.0-alpha1 and the issue is resolved but when i am trying to use firebase ui library  26.0.1 version is required. How to use 26.0.1 version?

Comment: What about `NoActionBar` in `Base`. What is the replacement for `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`?

Comment: @MarioVelasco you can use this very same theme as using noactionbar is not compulsory,  even I don't  have action bar but still  I'm using this... It causes no conflict.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` will create a default `ActionBar`. I 'm looking for a `NoActionBar` theme that solves the problem of this post.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar The `ActionBar` created with the `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` is not in the xml, it cannot be deleted.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar even an empty xml with that theme will create an `ActionBar`

Comment: I used the `Base` theme together with `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` and `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` in order to get an activity without `ActionBar`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154469/discussion-between-mario-velasco-and-lalit-singh-fauzdar).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error while using `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

**I replaced it by and it works fine**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am going throw the book "Head First Android Development A Brain-Friendly Guide" And this is the only good solution on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

In `styles.xml`,

Changing the theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` has worked for me.

Credit goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45399080/8111914

Answer (score 3):

If you have encountered one of these errors pasted below, you might need to review your settings in ***`styles.xml`*** files. I encountered this problem after I changed my build Tools in ***`build.gradle`*** file from ***`buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'`*** to ***`buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'`***

To specifically solve the problem, if you have a line similar to this

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

change it to include the **Base prefix**, for instance in my case I changed from

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

to

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

and everything worked fine.

The following classes could not be instantiated:

```
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard corded color value and after removing it everything worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Please change the theme style in 
res -> values -> Styles.xml

From :  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

To :  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved by changing `AppTheme` in `res -> values -> Styles.xml` change your theme from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
```